# ORA-04036: PGA memory used by the instance exceeds PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I came across ORA-04036 (on 12c) while one of my team members was creating an oracle text index.

```
ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
ORA-00039: error during periodic action
ORA-04036: PGA memory used by the instance exceeds PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 366
```

Answer (score 13):

in my case, It failed due to a very high parallel degree 48 (requiring too many session and increased PGA) while creating an index (or any other parallel operation). 
We should try to reduce parallelism to avoid this. I tried with DOP 8 script ran successfully.

> In Oracle Database 12c, a new parameter called PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT
>   sets a hard limit on the amount of PGA taken up by an instance. When
>   the overall PGA occupied by all the sessions in that instance exceed
>   the limit, Oracle kills the session holding the most untunable PGA
>   memory, releasing all PGA memory held by that session. That killed
>   session gets this message.
>
> Note the new Oracle error ORA-4036. This is an extremely useful
>   feature to control runaway PGA consumption by sessions issuing untuned
>   queries. The parameter pga_aggregate_limit, if not explicitly defined,
>   defaults to the greater of these three numbers: 2 GB 3 MB times the
>   value of the processes parameter 2 times the value of the parameter
>   pga_aggregate_target But this limit does not exceed the 1.2 times the
>   total physical memory after taking away the total SGA size. Don’t like
>   this new feature and want to go back to the previous (pre-12c)
>   behavior? Sure; just set the value of pga_aggregate_limit to 0 and the
>   parameter will not have any impact.

Posting answer in the interest of community readers as i could not find it on SO yet. Pls see [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/oracle-database-12c-manageability-2194094.html) for further reading...

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by doing the following.

See what the current pga_aggregate_limit is (in case you want to revert your changes) using this:

```
show parameter pga_aggregate_limit;
```

Set the pga_aggregate_limit to 0 using this:

```
alter system set pga_aggregate_limit = 0;
```

More information is available here:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pga_aggregate_limit.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-E364D0E5-19F2-4081-B55E-131DF09CFDB3.htm#REFRN10328